# JavaScript / Expressjs - app.del() route not working

Tags: javascript, express

I've put this JavaScript into my HTML code to try and add a functioning `delete` button to my page. I've tested the script to teset if it recognises the click and it does, but it isn't going through to my delete route, at the moment I am just testing the route so have only put a simple console log in it but here is the code. Any ideas?

```
script(type = 'text/javascript')
 $('#teamDelete').live('click', function () {
  var teamId = #{teamData.key};
  $.del('/team/' + teamId, function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

Route:

```
app.del('/team/:key', function(req, res) {
  util.log('Serving request for url [DEL] ' + req.route.path);
  util.log('success');
});
```

app:

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.enable('jsonp callback');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.set('view options', {layout : false});
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({
    secret : 'secretsecret'
  }));
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
  });
  app.use(app.router);
});
```

/team

```
    app.get('/team'/*, lim("Must be logged in to see teams")*/, getAllTeams, function(req, res){
    util.log('Serving request for url [GET] ' + req.route.path);
    // Pass it the list of all Teams
    res.render('team', {'teamsList' : req.teamsList} );
  });

  /**
    * POST /team
    * Save new Team
    */
  app.post('/team', function(req, res) {
    util.log('Serving request for url [POST] ' + req.route.path);

    // Output to console the contents of req.body
    // console.log('body: ', req.body);
    // console.log('body.teamForm: ', req.body.teamForm);
    // console.log('body.teamForm.name: ', req.body.teamForm.name);
    // console.log('body.teamForm.teamKey: ', req.body.teamForm.teamKey);

    // Get data from teamForm
    var teamForm = req.body.teamForm;

    // Save team in teamForm as new Team
    var name = teamForm.name;
    var team = new Team();
    team.name = name;

    // Save new Team to datbase
    team.save(function(err){
      var message = '';
      var retStatus = '';
      // No error - Successful Save
      if(!err){
        util.log('Successfully created new team: ' + name);
        message = 'Successfully created new team: ' + name;
        retStatus = 'success';
      } 
      // Error - Unsuccessful Save, show error
      else {
        util.log('Error while creating team: ' + name + ' error : ' + util.inspect(err));
        if(err.code === 11000){
          message = 'Team already exists';
        }
        retStatus = 'failure';
      }
      // Return whether the Save was successful
      res.json({
        'retStatus' : retStatus,
        'message' : message
      });
    });
  });

  /**
    * GET /team/:key
    * Get Team details by key
    */
  app.get('/team/:key', function(req, res) {
    util.log('Serving request for url [GET] ' + req.route.path);
    Team.findByKey(req.params.key, function(err, teamData){
      if(!err && teamData){
        teamData = teamData;
        res.render('teamDetails', { 'teamData' : teamData } );
      } else {
        util.log('Error in fetching Team by key : ' + req.params.key);
        res.json({
          'retStatus' : 'failure',
          'msg' : 'Error in fetching Team by key ' + req.params.key
        });
      }
    });
  });

  /**
    * DEL /team/:key
    * Delete Team by key
    */
  app.del('/team/:key', function(req, res) {
    util.log('Serving request for url [DEL] ' + req.route.path);

    util.log(req.params.key);

    Team.remove(req.params.key, function(err){
      var message = '';
      var retStatus = '';
      if (!err) {
        util.log('Successfully deleting Team with key: ' + req.params.key);
        message = 'Successfully deleting Team with key: ' + req.params.key;
        retStatus = 'Success';
      } else {
        util.log('Error deleting Team with key: ' + req.params.key + 'Error: ' + util.inspect(err));
        res.json({
          'retStatus' : 'failure',
          'msg' : 'Error in fetching Team with key ' + req.params.key
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.del()` doesn't exist. You can generate DELETE requests using `$.ajax`, but it's safer to use `$.post()`:

```
$.post('/team/' + teamId, { _method : 'delete' }, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

For this to work, you'll also need to use the `methodOverride` middleware in Express (*before* defining the `app.del` route):

```
app.use(express.bodyParser()); // this has to come before the next line
app.use(express.methodOverride());
```

Comment: so using this method I can safely use app.del in my routes? I just need to ensure I am using `methodOverride` in my middleware, which I'm sure I am anyway.

Comment: Yes, `methodOverride` is used to implement 'special' request types like DELETE and PUT, which aren't always supported by browsers. I edited by answer because you need to be aware that the `bodyParser` middleware has to be loaded as well (and that the order of using the middleware matters).

Comment: I have implemented this, and initially, when I clicked the delete button on Team 1's page, it logged in the console that it had been successfully deleted...but it has deleted ALL teams in the database, and when I try to create a new team which is using the .post(/team) route, it doesn't create any team at all. Any idea?

Comment: No idea without the actual code you use on your server, and the code you're using to create a new user.

Comment: I will update with my app code and new team code. Appreciate the help.

Comment: To reiterate sorry, once the code is added for my app.del() to delete a Team, it deletes ALL teams in the list rather than just the one. I can successfully create teams still but deleting wipes them all.

Comment: You're using Mongoose, right? I'm not sure if `Team.remove(string)` does anything, try `Team.remove({ _id : req.params.key }, ...)`.